# CSRF, CORS and my approach to authentication

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, csrf

I've seen many questions about CSRF attacks and GET requests, and I'm trying to work out what I need for my app's authentication system.

My stack is an SPA React app hosted at app.site.com, and an API at api.site.com.

My plan is to do the following.

1. On load, the React app will call a GET route on the server to get the current user.
2. This route will check the cookies, look for an httpOnly cookie with a valid token, and if so, send back a loggedin token which will be stored in application memory.
3. Each subsequent request will then be checked for both tokens in order to succeed.

A potential flaw in this that I can see is as follows:
Could an attacker send a victim to [www.other-domain.com](http://www.other-domain.com), which will trigger a script that calls my /user endpoint? That would send the httpOnly cookie, so the bad site/script will now get back my application memory token, and could then theoretically send other requests. I know I can protect against CORS with this, but is that enough?

I've read that CSRF is a 'write-only' attack, but in this instance I can see that it could be a problem on a GET request.

My questions, then, are:

1. Is the setup above workable from a security standpoint?
2. Would using a samesite cookie for the httponly cookie negate the need for the application memory token?
3. Are there any points in this process that I'm missing?

I've done a lot of research, but would love to hear the thoughts of more experienced engineers. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I would consider using the BFF pattern as described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw

Comment: Many thanks @ToreNestenius, watching this now.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that CSRF is a 'write-only' attack

In general you're right. CSRF can be used to execute a `create` or `delete` action (or any other side effect) on the server - which depending on your server implementation can also happen with a `GET` request. In some rare cases CSRF can also be used for DoS (Denial-of-Service), for example when you have a very expensive server-side computation in your API, that can be triggered too easy and often via CSRF.

> Are there any points in this process that I'm missing?

You would need CORS for your scenario to work (SPA on app.site.com and API on api.site.com). I'd try to avoid using CORS if possible, because `1.` it can introduce security problems if configured poorly, `2.` it can have a negative impact on performance when the browser runs preflight requests, which effectively will double the roundtrip time, and `3.` you introduce tight coupling between your SPA and your API.

And that's where BFF (backend for frontend) comes in handy: You simply use `app.site.com/api` for your API calls from your SPA, and your `app.site.com` server will act as a proxy and forward these requests to `api.site.com`.

Now you don't need CORS at all, and you decoupled your SPA and API, because now you can intercept your API calls at the BFF level and transform the requests made to the API and also transform the responses, aggregate data, combine multiple API requests, etc.